# JQuery action only works after page is reloaded

Tags: php, jquery, refresh, reload

I have the following code to display links based on the fact that a user is or is not logged:

```
<?php if(NOT LOGGED){ ?>
   <div id="menu"><ul><li><a class="login-button" href="login">LOGIN</a></li></ul></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
   <div id="menu"><ul><li><a class="logout-button" href="logout">EXIT</a></li></ul></div>
<?php } ?>
```

When the "login-button" is is clicked I call a JQuery function that on success will replace it with the following

```
<div id="menu"><ul><li><a class="logout-button" href="logout">EXIT</a></li></ul></div>
```

Here is the js

```
$.ajax({
url: 'login.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    $('#menu').html('<ul><li><a class="logout-button" href="logout">EXIT</a></li></ul>');
},
error: function (data) {
    alert('An Error occurred');
}
});
```

The problem is that when I click the logout link when it is created by JQuery it doesn´t work.

It only works when the page is refreshed and that is actually replaced by php

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you confirm your jQuery success function is called either via `alert()` or `console.log()` calls?

Comment: What happens when you click the "Logout" button? Does it run some JS function or just goes to the HREF url?

Comment: i think you're binding the click event with `.click()`. Try with `$(document).on('click', '.logout-button', function() { // the code you have now associated with .click()) }`. This is because the "logout" element doesn't exist when you are executing the code that binds the event. If you can provide even the JS code that binds the event, I can give a more precise answer.

Comment: The function is being called when I use alert(). Not sure why this is happening. It works for other similar parts on the code

Comment: Can I ask you how are you binding the event? I don't want to insist but it seems like the problem is that you are binding with `.click()` or anyway taking into consideration a element that (obviously, you will create it after the AJAX call) doesn't exist. This is why the `$(document).on('click', '.logout-button', function() { etc... });` (or even "#menu" in place of "document") should do the trick.

Comment: Well, It seems that the js file that contains the "login-button" action needs also to be included in the login.php page being called by ajax.

It´s strange because this js file is already loaded in the index.php page

INDEX.PHP

<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

LOGIN.PHP - Didn´t have that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it would fix the problem, but your removing the 'ul' in your success function

```
$('#menu').html('<li><a class="logout-button" href="logout">EXIT</a></li>');
```

Should be

```
$('#menu').html('<ul><li><a class="logout-button" href="logout">EXIT</a></li></ul>');
```

Comment: Not really. That was just my mistake not putting it there but it is actually there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are binding the event correctly (as @Lorenzo S says) but this does remind me of an issue I had which was solved by `.live`:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Up to quite recently that function was the one you would want but since jQuery 1.7 it has been replaced by `.on`:

http://api.jquery.com/on/